# How to calculate the mean of a specific value in columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop columns that have too many missing values. How can I count the occurrence of some values within columns since the missing values are represented using 99 or 90

here is the code that is supposed to drop columns that exceed the threshold value

```
threshold = 0.6

data = data[data.columns[[data.column == 90 or data.column == 99].count().mean() < threshold]]
```

I'm not quite used to using pandas, any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Also consider replacing the missing values by nans: `data.replace({90: np.NaN, 99: np.NaN}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Use `apply`:

```
threshold = 0.6
out = data[data.apply(lambda s: s.isin([90, 99])).mean(1).lt(threshold)]
```

Example input:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0  90   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   0  90   0  99   0
3  90   0   0   0   0
4  99  99   0  90  99  # to drop
5  99   0   0   0  99
6   0   0  99   0  90
7   0  90  99   0  90  #
8  99  90   0  90   0  #
9   0  99   0   0   0
```

output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0  90   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   0  90   0  99   0
3  90   0   0   0   0
5  99   0   0   0  99
6   0   0  99   0  90
9   0  99   0   0   0
```

Comment: Then `data.loc[:, data.apply(lambda s: s.isin([90, 99])).mean().lt(threshold)]`. (Btw, if speed is a concern you can also use numpy here).